# Summernote Not Converting HTML

Tags: php, laravel, summernote

I can't seem to convert HTML code I retrieve from my database to convert HTML tags such as

```
<p> or <img>
```

into regular markup.

Here's what I currently am using.

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
      var titleEditor = $('#titleDiv').summernote();
      var contentEditor = $('#contentDiv').summernote();
      titleEditor.summernote('code', "{{$Article->name}}")
      contentEditor.summernote('code', "{{$Article->content}}")
    });
</script>
```

and my HTML

```
<div class="panel-heading" style="overflow: hidden;">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div id="titleDiv">
          Title Goes Here
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <div id="contentDiv">
        Content Goes Here (Don't worry, it'll auto-expand)
      </div>
    </div>
```

I've tried every iteration.

Anyone know of any way to fix this? My incessant googling couldn't solve anything.

- Zach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to tell blade not to escape html code by using {!! !!} syntax
check display data as unescaped.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/blade#displaying-data

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
      var titleEditor = $('#titleDiv').summernote();
      var contentEditor = $('#contentDiv').summernote();
      titleEditor.summernote('code', "{!! $Article->name !!}")
      contentEditor.summernote('code', "{!! $Article->content !!}")
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you! Thought it was a summernote bug, not an issue with Laravel!